# Ubuntu 14.10 Grub menu does not permit to choose Window 8.1

Tags: dual-boot

I've faced the issue of dual OS booting from the single HDD ( using BIOS desktop ),Ubuntu boots promptly ignoring  "->" keys strikes - Is it an improper installation or BIOS causation I wonder?

```
/dev/sda1  *           63 409601407 409601345 195,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       409602048 438898687  29296640    14G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       438898688 446711807   7813120   3,7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       446711808 976771071 530059264 252,8G 83 Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you see the GRUB screen, but keys do not work so you cannot boot anything except the default selection?

This can happen because you don't have USB Keyboard support enabled in your BIOS.